# My await code doesn't wait my code to proceed

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

I'm trying to make a code that get the paths of all files in a project and stores it in an array, but when I try to use the array it comes back empty, even using async await the code does not wait for the execution of the snippet to proceed.

```
const glob = require("glob");

var allfiles = [];

inicio();

async function inicio() {
    await gerall();

    console.log(allfiles);
}

async function gerall() {
    var getDirectories = function(src, callback) {
        glob(src + '/**/*', callback);
    };
    await getDirectories('./', function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        } else {
            res.forEach(element => {
                if (!element.includes("node_module") &&
                    !element.includes("package.json") &&
                    !element.includes("package-lock.json") &&
                    element.substring(1).includes(".")) {
                    allfiles.push(element);

                }
            });

        }
    })


}
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

sorry for my english.

Comment: `getDirectories()` doesn't return a promise, and it doesn't wait for the callback.

Comment: You can't use `await` with a function that takes a callback.  You can use `promisify` to wrap `getDirectories` to return a promise around a traditional (err, result) callback.

Answer (score 0):

remove the await on getDirectories, because this is not a promise-returning function.  It is a callback style, and the resulting code after this will execute only when getDirectories finishes.

Comment: hello G-Force,  i've fixed this, but my problem is in the inicio function, because even with await it does not wait for the execution to log.

Comment: Nevermind, that solved, I'm going to do the code in the getDirectories function, it's a simple code.

Comment: the inicio function won't wait.  If you had promise-based code, then you could "await" gerall(), followed by a .then() and .catch(), for which the console.log inside the .then() would work as you want.  But because you don't have promises, then implementing inside the callbacks and stripping off the async/await (only for promises) is the right way to go....or promisify everything, if you want to learn that.